# Page goes dead on IE9 if cache is on

Tags: internet-explorer-9, flash, compatibility, browser-cache

This was a strange bug to encounter: while on IE9, refreshing without cache seems fine, but with cache on the page goes dead.

Answer (score 0):

Problem (see details [here](http://www.q-trax.co.uk/blog/as/avoidbrowsercaching.htm)):

> When we test a Flash movie in a web page, the SWF may be cached by the browser software, so that when we make modifications to the SWF, the browser may continue to display the cached version of the SWF and ignore any new version.

Solution:

adding a time stamp `new Date().getTime()`, thereby force refresh from browser every time:

```
embedpano({
    swf: "xx.swf?_t=" + new Date().getTime(),
    xml: "xx.xml",
    target: "pano",
    html5: "prefer",
    bgcolor:"#323232",
    passQueryParameters: true
});
```

It's said that methods as such don't work in IE7, and if you want it dealt with, check out AS solutions in the link above.

Comment: *"The flash plugin seems to be retrieving old data related to swf files whenever possible."* - You need to explain it better than that.  Right now, your answer is reminiscent of a voodoo programming solution.

Comment: @StephenC Good suggestion, I'll do some research and clarify.